# Ancestry - how to get all parent without children?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ancestry

I am doing it this way:

```
@disabled_options = []
Category.where('ancestry is NULL').each do |cat|
  @disabled_options << cat.id if cat.has_children?
end
```

Is there any more elegant way to get all parent without children?

Comment: do you want to find all 'parents' (all categories that have children) or do you want to find all 'roots' (all categories that have no parents)?

Comment: all categories that have children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Category.where("id IN (SELECT parent_id FROM categories)")
```

Assuming `parent_id` is a field pointing to the parent category.

This will select those categories that are pointed to using "parent_id", so if there's a child, the child will have "parent_id" set, therefore the category referenced to by "parent_id" has children.

Answer (score 2):

This one-liner may help you.

```
Category.where(id: Category.pluck(:ancestry).compact.map { |e| e.split('/') }.flatten.uniq)
```