# Rails Ancestry Gem: how to write scope to match all parents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ancestry

Using the Rails `ancestry` gem ,
what is the best way to write a scope on the User model to find all records which have children / which are parents?

```
class User < ActiveRecords::Base
  has_ancestry

   def is_manager?
     has_children
   end

   scope :is_manager, -> { ... ? ... }

end
```

Comment: Is there just one User Tree? (is there more than one node with nil as ancestry).
How big are the trees (~ number nodes, depth) , how many trees?

Comment: Let's assume there are multiple trees, each with thousands of records in the tree -- e.g. org charts for companies in a SaaS application

Answer (score 1):

try this, I think that is the best way

```
scope :is_manager, -> {where(id: User.pluck(:ancestry).compact.map { |e| e.split('/') }.flatten.uniq)}
```

it select only ancestry field from the database, remove nil, split it and take the number, flatten it, and make it uniq, then select all User based on it.

also check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366663/ancestry-how-to-get-all-parent-without-children)

Comment: You might want to add a `distinct` before `pluck`. Depends on the DB though.

Comment: The downside of this is that it loads every user in the DB into memory..
@icemelt is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Along the same lines as icemelt's answer..

this does the same, but instead of loading all the records from the database into memory, it only selects the unique ancestries and processes them - that should make a bit of a difference in terms of memory impact

```
scope :is_manager, -> { where(id: User.select(:ancestry).distinct.pluck(:ancestry).compact.map { |x| x.split('/') }.flatten.uniq) }
```